# Sonos search never available for customSD music service

Tags: sonos

We are adding the search feature to our music service on Sonos, following the instructions in the Sonos API docs, but when testing with the Windows Sonos desktop application, there is no search available for our application.

Presentation Map

```
<PresentationMap type="Search">
    <Match>
        <SearchCategories>
            <Category id="artists" mappedId="search/artist"/>  
        </SearchCategories>
    </Match>
</PresentationMap>
```

Using SoapUI, manual testing of getMetadata(search) returns:

```
<getMetadataResult>
    <index>0</index>
    <count>1</count>
    <total>1</total>
    <mediaCollection>
        <id>search/artist</id>
        <itemType>search</itemType>
        <title>search/artist</title>
    </mediaCollection>
</getMetadataResult>
```

and search(Search parameter) returns valid entries.

The self-test for search passes all tests as well. When adding the music service to the player (customSD), the "Search" capability is selected.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Did I miss a step?

I have not tested using the android/iOS controller app.

Answer (score 1):

So I think the issue is with your id ="artists." Since you are returning "search/artist" in the title in your getMetdata response this isn't matching up. You would either need to be returning "artists" in this field or mapping to a stringId = "search/artist" in your strings file to change this to a custom category in the controller. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the issue was with the version of the Sonos desktop controller. Reinstalling the controller with the latest version from the Sonos website (6.1.1) resolved the issue, and the search option for out application now appears as expected.